# overwriting a value in a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframe columns that's consist of True, False and NA values, these values are of type str. How can i merge these dataframe columns together to make another dataframe column that makes the false values overwrite the true values when the 2 dataframe columns are fused together?
if the columns were bools i could just use the "&" function but i can't seem to figure it out as the values are strings.

i was thinking of adding them together and then trying to do something with that.

df["merged"] = df["column 1"] + df["column 2"]

but i think im on the wrong track

Comment: Convert the column dtype to bool and then use &? you may wanna fill NAN values as False if you want to treat them as Fasle.

Comment: The problem is I need to keep N/A values as i need to use them in calculations further down the line.

Comment: Will you include a sample of your df and a sample of your desired output as code? It would be helpful to _see_ what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function for this and then apply it across the DataFrame,
My first condition means, if the values in the column are the same, retain the value in the third column, assuming that you want the same for 'NA'.
The second and third condition, is to choose, either "True" or "False" when the other column has "NA" value.
And for all other cases, returns "False", i.e if one column has a "True" value and the other "False", this should work:

```
def and_func(x):
   if x["column 1"] == x["column 2"]:
       return x["column 1"]
   elif ((x["column 1"] == 'NA') & (x["column 2"] != 'NA')):
       return x["column 2"]
   elif ((x["column 2"] == 'NA') & (x["column 1"] != 'NA')):
       return x["column 1"]
   else:
       return "False"


df["merged"] = df.apply(lambda x: and_func(x), axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the `True` and `False` string values to booleans and the `NA` string value to pandas [nullable boolean type](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/boolean.html) with:

```
d = {'True': True, 'False': False, 'NA': pd.NA}

df['column 1'] = df['column 1'].map(d).astype('boolean')
```

Then you can perform the logical comparison between the two columns with `&`.